# Angular - Unable to send data with POST request to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, post

I'm trying to make an authentication system inside my website. I'm sending a simple POST request with the email and password inside, to my ASP.NET server and for some reason the data (email and password) inside the server is empty. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'm a beginner on ASP.NET and Angular.

**Angular code: (I tried to show the text from the text boxes inside some elements and it shows the correct text)**

```js
  isUserLoggedIn: boolean;
  emailAddress: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {}

  login() {

    const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', };
    const body = { emailAddress: this.emailAddress.toString, password: this.password.toString };
    this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "login", body, { headers }).subscribe(result => {
      this.isUserLoggedIn = result;
      if (this.isUserLoggedIn) console.log("Logged in")
      else console.log("Not logged in")
    }, error => console.error(error));

  }
```

**My ASP.NET controller:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public bool LoginUser(string emailAddress, string password)
{
    // DOES NOT PRINT ANY VALUE OF EMAIL OR PASSWORD
    Console.WriteLine("1: " + emailAddress);
    Console.WriteLine("2: " + password);
            
    SakilaContext context = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(SakilaContext)) as SakilaContext;
    return context.LoginUser(emailAddress, password);
}
```

**My code for database inside ASP.NET server:**

```cs
public bool LoginUser(string emailAddress, string password)
{
    bool isUserLoggedIn = false;
    List<UserModel> list = new List<UserModel>();
    using (MySqlConnection conn = GetConnection())
    {
        string query = $"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{emailAddress}'";
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    string db_password = reader.GetString("password");
                    if (db_password == password)
                    {
                        isUserLoggedIn = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isUserLoggedIn;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `LoginModel` class.

```cs
public class LoginModel
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Change the `Login` method signature to read the object value from the request body via `[FromBody]`.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public bool LoginUser([FromBody] LoginModel model)
{
    Console.WriteLine(model.EmailAddress);
    Console.WriteLine(model.Password);

    ...
}
```

For Angular, I don't think the below part is correct:

```
const body = { emailAddress: this.emailAddress.toString, password: this.password.toString };
```

Change to

```
const body = { emailAddress: this.emailAddress.toString(), password: this.password.toString() };
```

Or

```
const body = { emailAddress: this.emailAddress, password: this.password };
```

---

**Side note:**

Don't concatenate the value in SQL command, use a parameterized query with [`.AddWithValue("@parameter", value)`](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/). Check out [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements).

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = @emailAddress";
conn.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailAddress", emailAddress);
```

---

**Reference**

[`[FromBody]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#frombody-attribute)

Comment: Still not working :((

Comment: Hi, did you check the browser DevTools Netwotk tab, did you post the request with value? And in Angular side, I think this is wrong `this.emailAddress.toString`, use `this.emailAddress.toString()`. Same goes for `password`.

Comment: ichecked it and it doesn't send any data for some reason, the data inside the payload is empty

Comment: i fixed the problem by converting .toString to .toString()